# How to fix variable not equaling user input

Tags: java, variables, methods

My program asks the user for a number and then validates if the number is either within the range of two randomly generated numbers or outside the range. The variable num is supposed to be the user's guess, but it keeps equating to 0. I'm uncertain if it has to do with the num = 0 in main, which is there because I get a "variable might not of been initialized" error if the = 0 is not there.

Code:

```
public static int getValidGuess(Scanner get)
    {
       int num;

        System.out.print("Guess a number: --> ");
        num = get.nextInt();

        return num;
    } // getValidGuess end

    public static boolean displayGuessResults(int start, int end, int num)
    {

      boolean result;

    Random gen = new Random();

    int n1 = gen.nextInt(99) + 1;
    int n2 = gen.nextInt(99) + 1;


    if (n1 < n2){
        start = n1;
        end = n2;
    } //if end
    else
    {
        start = n2;
        end = n1;
    } //else end
    System.out.println("\nThe 2 random numbers are " + start + " and " + end);
    System.out.println("User Guess is " + num);
    if(num >= start && num <= end){
        result = true;
        System.out.println("Good Guess!");
    }
    else if(num < start || num > end){
        result = false;
        System.out.println("Outside Range.");
    }
    else{
        result = false;
    }
    return result;

    } // displayGuessResults end

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start code here
       int start = 0, end = 0, num = 0;
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       String doAgain = "Yes";

        while (doAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
            // call method
            getValidGuess(scan); 
            displayGuessResults(start, end, num);
            System.out.print("\nEnter YES to repeat --> ");
            doAgain = scan.next();
        } //end while loop

    } //main end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in different functions aren't magically the same just because they have the same name. If you want to be able to share variables without passing them as parameters or return values, then you need to declare them in the class instead.

Specifically, here's your two choices. Choice 1 (recommended): change `getValidGuess(scan);` to `num = getValidGuess(scan);`. Choice 2: put `public static int num = 0;` right in your class, outside all of your functions, and remove the declarations of `num` from all of your functions.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Though I am a bit confused on how, any tips?

Comment: @Kaiju It is much better to pass them as parameters, though. The best practice is to keep data items in as small of a scope as possible, so "variable that only lives inside this method" is _much_ better than "variable stored outside it in the containing class". In particular, when you have code that gets called many times (like in a server), you don't want multiple executions interrupting each other.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica